# Reading large gz files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 gzip files each around 30GB in size and have written spark code to analyze them. The spark cluster has 4 worker nodes (28GB RAM and 4 cores each) and 2 head nodes ( 64GB RAM).

I am using `sc.textFile(histfile,20)` to read these 2 gzip files and parallelize them. The job is divided in 3 stages - `reduceByKey`, `reduceByKey` and `saveAsTextFile`. As there are 2 files, only 2 workers are being utilized as of now.

It has taken more than 4 hours and still the 1st stage is not finished. 
What is the right way to run spark jobs when each gzip file is 100GB-200GB in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gzip file is not spllitable hence your first stage will spawn two map task and it will take a lot of time for the first stage to pass.

Please repartition before the second phase for a good distribution to reduce task.

Comment: Thank you, the num.executor.instances is set as 20. Does `sc.textFile(file,numpartition)`  not partition and achieve parallelism ?

Comment: The input formats of Spark are coming from Hadoop.  numpartition will come into effect only in case of splittable files. In your case there is no splitting hence numpartitions is not of any use. You can view the num task in stage 1 to verify the same.